# Why picturebox is never updated?

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox, aforge

I have a very simple forms app where i read a video from my computer and for each frame i want to update picturebox with the current frame. I thought it would be straight forward, but my picturebox is always empty.

```
private void loadPicture()
{
    VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
    reader.Open("local link to video");
    Console.WriteLine(reader.FrameCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FrameCount; i++)
    {
        Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Dispose();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = videoFrame;
        //Console.WriteLine(pictureBox1.Image.Height);
        videoFrame.Dispose();
    }
    reader.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadPicture();
}
```

I use the `Aforge.Video.FFMPEG` library to read the video.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is `form_load_1` the actual form load event? also, you dispose the *picturebox* which is the control

Comment: ah.... pictutrebox.image.dispose() fixed it :)

Comment: Why don't you try using the debugger, by stepping through the code bugs like this reveal themselves quite easily.

Comment: put hard coded FrameCount in for loop,  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) for testing

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a small error while `Disposing`:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    pictureBox1.Dispose();
}
```

but this disposes the whole `PictureBox` so please call

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
}
```

instead.